# Host http:// and https:// for same domain on separate IIS servers

Tags: iis, https

Is it possible to host http://example.com and https://example.com on two separate IIS servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any decent router could do this as well, route 433 to serv1 and 80 to serv2.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one IP address has to be authoritative for the DNS name. However, that device could be an Apache machine with ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse that could send the requests to the right server. Also, I think IIS 7.0 has pretty good redirection now too, so you could host both on (for example) the server that serves HTTP, but just make it proxy or redirect to another server for HTTPS.

Comment: It would be better to redirect it at the network level with some firewall rules.

Comment: That works too.